# Is Halide math performed in "float" (32-bit)?

Tags: halide

I am writing Halide code and I have declared a Buffer< double> input as the input to my Halide function. However, I am not sure if that makes any sense since Halide tutorial#1 says

```
// Halide does type inference for you. Var objects represent
// 32-bit integers, so the Expr object 'x + y' also represents a
// 32-bit integer, and so 'gradient' defines a 32-bit image, and
// so we got a 32-bit signed integer image out when we call
// 'realize'. Halide types and type-casting rules are equivalent
// to C.
```

I can run the function without any problems, but I am not sure if there is some typecasting being done to convert my double to float without me even knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Good question! (We need more and better documentation.)

It is perfectly reasonable to use `double`s. Much like in C (with those C-style type promotion rules mentioned in the comment you quoted), `double <op> float` or `double <op> int` will perform computation in and return results as `double`.

If, for example, you have your `Buffer<double> input`, then:

```cpp
Func f; Var x, y;
f(x,y) = input(x,y)*2;
```

with infer type type of `f` as `double`, as well. You’ll notice this if you check the type of the buffer you get out as the result. As in C, the `int` constant `2` will be promoted to `double` before multiplication, and the result will be stored as `double`. The type of each `Func` is just given by the inferred type of the right hand side `Expr` which first defines it.

Types are *promoted* automatically, never *demoted*. If you want to constrain the type of the result you can use explicit `cast`s in your expressions.

Does that make sense?